# How to tell if cert has private key

Tags: c#, rsa, certificate, private-key

I've got a keystore that is full of certificates. Another person has told me the certificates have a private key but when i check in my code i never see any. All of these keys were used in vs6 and cryptapi, i'm using c#.

I created my own certificate and ensured it had a private key by using the methods here 
http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/vbasic/3.htm

When i imported that into the same keystore and then ran my code that cert showed that it did indeed have a private key, all of the other certs in the key store dont (according to my code).

Is there some flag or something i need to set in order to be able to use the private key within the certs in this keystore ?

```
public void testForPrivateKey(string keystorename)
{
    X509Store teststore = new X509Store(keystorename);

    teststore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in teststore.Certificates)
    {
        if(cert.HasPrivateKey)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Private key found certificate name: {0}", cert.Subject);
        }

    }
    store.Close();

}
```

Comment: Found out that the keys are in the "key container" not the "certificate store" Does anyone know how I can specify the key that I will use to do the encrypt/decrypt given that there are exchange/signature keys and others in the key container.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same question, but resolved after investigating:
If a cert has private key, it has the property CERT_KEY_SPEC_PROP_ID also.

```
DWORD  keySpec;
DWORD len = 4;
BOOL ret = CertGetCertificateContextProperty(pCertContext, CERT_KEY_SPEC_PROP_ID, &keySpec, &len);
if ( !ret ){
    //has no private key
}
```

Comment: I do not see it for my certificates. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

A key is associated with a cert. You don't pick one, it's determined by the cert you're using. See the [EncryptTo/DecryptTo: Encryption in .NET with CryptoAPI Certificate Stores](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms867080.aspx) article on MSDN.